# How do I know Sms Sending is blocked by permission check?

Tags: android, sms

Here blow is the code:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(target, null, content, sentPI, delieveredPI);
```

I have declared using permission of "android.permission.SEND_SMS" in AndroidManifest.xml.
But on some phones, when sending sms with api, a dialog asking for permission pops up, and if user choose "Not grant" the permission, the sms sending will fail silently, without any callback or broadcast.
Question is: Is there any method to detect this kind of blocking?

Answer (score 4):

> But on some phones, when sending sms with api, a dialog asking for permission pops up

Yes, this will happen on Android [Marshmallow](https://www.android.com/versions/marshmallow-6-0/) devices that has a new runtime permission model.

You need to use the `checkSelfPermission` method before you try and use this permission, as such:

```
if (Context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                                  != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   // permission is not granted, ask for permission:
   requestPermissions(this, //assuming this is Activity or a subclass of it
            new String[] { Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
            MY_KEY_FOR_RETURNED_VALUE);
 }
```

Optionally, you could (and should) also display a rationale to the user (first checking if Android will even ask the user for that permission using `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` - the user won't be prompted if, for example, he denied and marked "don't ask me again" so you should check first and not always display).

Then check the request answer in your implementation of `onRequestPermissionsResult`:

```
@override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
    String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == MY_KEY_FOR_RETURNED_VALUE) {
       if (grantResults.length > 0
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

           // permission is granted
       }
    }
```

You can find more information either [here](http://blog.safedk.com/technology/the-marshmallows-are-coming-new-permissions-model-is-almost-here/) or in the official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: Thank you, I know this new feature in 6.0, but some device maker even implemented the permission check in their own way on their system below 6.0, such as Xiaomi, Huawei, etc. On these phones, the call will be consumed silently if user choose no, NOTHING will happen...

Comment: I see. That wasn't clear from your question. Anyway, I'm not sure if there's a way to detect it. I assume the did `PackageManager.checkPermission` wouldn't work, but it's worth a try. You may also want to look at `AppOpsManager` class (using `((AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE)).checkOpNoThrow(permission, android.os.Process.myUid(), context.getPackageName());`. Other than that, I'll just suggest `try/catch`. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Thank you again! Your assumption is right, checkPermission doesn't work, it simply extract the value from AndroidManifest, I'll try with AppOpsManager.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I use to check permissions -

```
// Check Permission fails on Android OSes below Marshmallow, so the below if sentence is necessary
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
            REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, I know this new feature in 6.0, but some device maker even implemented the permission check in their own way on their system below 6.0, such as Xiaomi, Huawei, etc. On these phones, the call will be consumed silently if user choose no, NOTHING will happen...

Comment: @ZhangYu They have to go to settings and manually grant the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

For android 6.0 up, I use

`boolean isBlocked =  shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);`

to check whether permission is check **Never Ask Again.**

if `isBlocked` return true, permission is just clicked denied.

if `isBlocked` return false, permission is checked **Never Ask Again.** and the permission is blocked.

Check Build Version first before use the method.

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= M){
boolean isBlocked =      shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
}`

This is [Documentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: **isBlocked** will return false for first time OS show permission dialog be careful